# How do I reference Google Material-Design-Icons after npm install?

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, material-design, material-ui

So after doing `npm install material-design-icons`, how do I use them in my `React` application?

The methods included [here](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web) doesn't include the `npm` method.

Comment: I would recommend to use [free icons from here](https://iconmonstr.com/about/). Easier to use. And heavily optimized

Answer (score 45):

This is the way you can reference it (in your styles.css):

```
@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

To use it:

```
<i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i>
```

Comment: Thank you!   Worked on this for hours until I read your solution.

Answer (score 10):

Open `angular.json` in your project, and add the following line `node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css` under `projects => YOUR_APP => architect => options => styles`

[image: add new stylesheet to angular project]

**My angular version `ng version`:**

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.3 
Node: 11.15.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.0.1
```

Comment: Funny how this Angular answer is posted under a React question, it was helpful nonetheless :)

Answer (score 6):

Use this in `index.html` file after `npm install material-design-icons` .
It works in my Angular Project.

```
<link href="../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#icons) which provides two components to render system icons: [`SvgIcon`](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svg-material-icons) for rendering SVG paths, and [`Icon`](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#font-material-icons) for rendering font icons.

If you are not already using [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#installation) in your project, you can add it with:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

***SVG Material icons***:

*Material-UI* provides a separate npm package, [@material-ui/icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons), that includes the 1,000+ official [Material icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) converted to `SvgIcon` components

**1. Installation**:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/icons

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

**2. Import the icons**:

```
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
import ThreeDRotation from '@material-ui/icons/ThreeDRotation';
```

**3. Usage**:

You can use [material.io/tools/icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) to find a specific icon. When importing an icon, keep in mind that the names of the icons are `PascalCase`, for instance:

- `delete` is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/Delete`
- `delete forever` is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/DeleteForever`

For *themed* icons, append the theme name to the icon name. For instance with the

- The *Outlined* `delete` icon is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutlined`
- The *Rounded* `delete` icon is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/DeleteRounded`
- The *Two Tone* `delete` icon is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/DeleteTwoTone`
- The *Sharp* `delete` icon is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/DeleteSharp`

There are three exceptions to this rule:

- `3d_rotation` is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/ThreeDRotation`
- `4k` is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/FourK`
- `360` is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/ThreeSixty`

***Font Material icons***:

**1. Include [Material icon font](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web) in your project, via Google Web Fonts**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

**2. Import `Icon` component:**

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
```

**3. wrap the icon name with the Icon component, for example**:

```
<Icon>star</Icon>
```

more info [here](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#icons)

Comment: In React, you then can use the imported icons like this: `<DeleteForever />`

Answer (score 1):

Using npm & laravel-mix you can do this:

```
// Material Design Icons - File: sass/app.scss
@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

cmd:

```
npm run dev
```

html:

```
<i class="material-icons"> list </i>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a copy of the "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css", changed the `url`s in the file and then imported that copied file in my main stylesheet.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot'); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url('~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me with laravel 8 & npm:

```
//terminal:
npm install material-design-icons
```

Then in your *webpack.mix.js* add

```
.postCss('node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css', 'public/css')
```

so it would look more-less like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.postCss('node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css', 'public/css')
.sourceMaps();
```

Next

```
//terminal
npm run dev
```

Because of that you will get *material-icons.css* file in your public folder so now, all you have to do is to include it in your html.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/material-icons.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```