# How to include new google material design icon inside node modules?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Currently working on a project which needs import of google material design icons. Few Icons are able to render as I installed google material design package using following command:

`npm install @material-ui/icons`

`npm install @material-ui/core`

Inside my `JavaScript` file I am importing following two Icons:

`import EmojiObjects from '@material-ui/icons/EmojiObjectsSharp';`

`import {Construction} from '@material-ui/icons/Construc';`

Inside the `Header` function of `JavaScript` file:

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a><Link to="/products"><AddShoppingCart/>Produkte</Link></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><Link to="/solutions"><EmojiObjects/>Lösungen</Link></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><Link to="/tools"><Construction/>Tools</Link></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><Link to="/tools">Unternehmen</Link></a></li>
```

May I ask please what is the mistake am I doing? I do not see the file inside my node modules folder which is related to `Construction`icon.

Is there a way to insert new google material design icons?

**I tried to solve the problem using follwing website but there is no description for `Construction` icon.**

https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/#material-icons

Answer (score 0):

`Construction` icon is not part of the default set, as you mentioned. You can however use `SvgIcon` component MUI provides as described [here](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svgicon):

```
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon'

function ConstructionIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" /> // <- replace with correct SVG
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
```

And to get the SVG you can grab it from [here](https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=constru&icon=construction&style=baseline), or if you really want to import it to your `node_modules` you can do `npm i material-design-icons`, and include into your codebase as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650142/731782).

**Edit**:

Option 1:

As per the link provided, after `npm i material-design-icons` you will need to add the css to your project:

```
@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

and then reference the icon with:

```
<i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i>
```

Option 2:

Import the web fonts in your `styles.css`:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons&display=swap");
```

and then add to your component (Mine is `App.js`):

```
import React from "react";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return <Icon>construction</Icon>;
}
```

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-glade-p6mc9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you for your answer. May I ask please which path should I include for the path component?